# Can't complete mysql request in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, tedious

I am using the exact code (changing the local host and password exec) that I get off the mssql site https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql. I only have one table and I just want to complete a query.

```
var sql = require('mssql');

sql.connect("mssql://root:password@localhost:3306/testdb").then(function() {

new sql.Request()
  .query('select * from scores').then(function(recordset) {
    console.dir(recordset);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
});

}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I used "npm install mssql" and it didn't have any problems. I run it with the "new sql.Request()...." part removed and it runs with no errors. I take this to mean that it connects to the SQL server successfully.

SQL server is on or at least workbench tells me it is on.

Then I add in my bare bones query and I get a stack index out of range exception. I have no idea what exactly is causing it.

I get this very unhelpful error.

```
buffer.js:613
throw new RangeError('index out of range');
^

RangeError: index out of range
at checkOffset (buffer.js:613:11)
at Buffer.readUInt8 (buffer.js:651:5)
at Packet.isLast (E:\Space!\WebDesign\SQL server\node_modules\mssql\node_mod
ules\tedious\lib\packet.js:112:29)
at ReadablePacketStream.<anonymous> (E:\Space!\WebDesign\SQL server\node_mod
ules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\message-io.js:91:18)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at ReadablePacketStream.emit (events.js:169:7)
at readableAddChunk (E:\Space!\WebDesign\SQL server\node_modules\mssql\node_
modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:210:18)
at ReadablePacketStream.Readable.push (E:\Space!\WebDesign\SQL server\node_m
odules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_reada
ble.js:169:10)
at ReadablePacketStream.Transform.push (E:\Space!\WebDesign\SQL server\node_
modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_tran
sform.js:123:32)
at ReadablePacketStream._transform (E:\Space!\WebDesign\SQL server\node_modu
les\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\message-io.js:57:16)
```

I would like this to not happen any one know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to look at using [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/) as a minimal database layer before getting too committed to writing directly to the driver. Can you explain why you're using the Microsoft SQL Server (`mssql`) driver to connect to MySQL? That's not going to work.

Comment: What stack overflow exception? That looks like a `RangeError` to me..

Comment: your right I must have miss typed it's not stack overflow. I am using SQL server because I am practicing for a new internship and they want mysql experience.

Comment: `mssql` and `mysql` are _two different things_. The first is the driver for Microsoft SQL Server, the second for MySQL. It looks like you're trying to connect to a MySQL database using the SQL Server driver.

Comment: Try to execute `select * from scores limit 1`. Looks like your recordset too big. And, if you can, provide your table structure.